# Cron Expression for dynamic schedule

Tags: quartz-scheduler, cronexpression

I am looking for a Cron Expression that will schedule in different time in different weekdays. I'm not sure if that is possible or not.

I searched and found that Cron can schedule `"At 8:00am every Monday through Friday"` or `"At 1:30am every last Friday of the month"`.

But is it possible to get cron expression that will schedule like, say :

```
10:00 AM every Monday
12:00 AM every Tuesday
02:00 PM every Wednesday
04:00 PM every Thursday
06:00 AM every Friday
```

I'm new to Cron Expression, and through google, I could not find whether it is possible.

My query is :

1. Is it possible to create cron expression like that?
2. If possible, then can you provide sample expression for that? along with some tutorial to know how to create them.

Answer (score 1):

1. No, you need to write a different cron expression for each time-day(s) combination.
2. Ubuntu has a [nice tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto#Crontab_Sections) about cron. To run something at 10:00 AM every Monday:

   ```
   # Min Hr  Day Month  Weekday   Command
     00  10  *   *      1         touch /tmp/cron_has_run
   ```

Note that weekdays are counted from zero, so 0 is Sunday, 1 is Monday, etc.

Comment: to run every Monday 10:00 AM, that is ok, I was aware of that. I was wondering about different day-time combination. Anyway, thanks for the quick response.